# PHP get parameter and session

Tags: php, session

If this code in redir.php

```
$param = $_GET["redirect"];
$allowed = array(
    "index" => "index.php",
    "login"  => "login.php",
    // ...and so on...
);
$redirect = isset($allowed[$param]) ? $allowed[$param] : "index.php?ref=redir";
header('Location: '.$redirect);
```

How to include `session_unset(); session_destroy();` in the redir.php so I can make a request like example.com/redir.php?redirect=index&session_unset_session_destroy=true

How to include this into script.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @Michael, I don't think so, he's just asking how to get and read the session_unset_session_destroy parameter...

Comment: @Alberto I was too fast on the keyboard, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code with this:

```
session_start();
$options = $_GET;
if(isset($options['redirect']))
{
    $allowed = array(
        "index" => "index.php",
        "login"  => "login.php",
        // ...and so on...
    );
    $redirect = isset($allowed[$options['redirect']]) ? $allowed[$options['redirect']] : "index.php?ref=redir";

    if(isset($options['session_unset_session_destroy']) && $options['session_unset_session_destroy']=="true")
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    header('Location: '.$redirect);
}
```

Now if you request `example.com/redir.php?redirect=index&session_unset_session_destroy=true`, the session will be unset and destroyed.

Comment: how to make redirect to index if no parameter attached?

Comment: Add an else to the if and redirect the user.